# One of my clip's Preview's isn't showing and the timeline color isn't showing in Adobe Premiere Pro. What should I do?

Tags: premiere, adobe

Me and my partner are working on a project in Premiere Pro of which I saved on the Creative Cloud directory and carefully synced all the files. My partner (who shot the video) from the other end created a sequence and makes some cuts on different clips so that I can take it from there and continue with the editing. However, after she's done trimming the clips she informed me so that I can have a look. but, when I open the projects there's a particular spot on the line that instead of showing the usual Yellow Line just like the rest of the section of the clip, the Yellow line wasn't there and that particular clip doesn't show anything on the preview despite the fact that the clip is still there in the project panel. please Help.
[image]